# How to get OSX finder to calculate duration and bit rate in finder window preview

Tags: macos, mac, audio, osx-lion, finder

I cannot figure out how to get the preview area (to the right side of selected audio files) in finder windows to display the correct data.  If anyone has a suggestion of how to force Finder to either display these metadata, or to force a calculation into that value slot, I'd appreciate it.

osx 10.7.5

Comment: What audio file formats?

Comment: AIFF and WAVE.  MP3 works by default, AFAICT.

Answer (score 2):

Finder does show the duration and bit rate for both wav and aiff files on my installation.

You could see if the metadata is shown by mdls or after reimporting some directory with mdimport. Or delete the Spotlight local stores with `sudo mdutil -Ea`.

Another way to show information about audio files is to use `afinfo`:

```
$ afinfo /System/Library/Sounds/Basso.aiff
File:           /System/Library/Sounds/Basso.aiff
File type ID:   AIFF
Num Tracks:     1
----
Data format:     2 ch,  22050 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x0000000E) 16-bit big-endian signed integer
                no channel layout.
estimated duration: 0.164490 sec
audio bytes: 14508
audio packets: 3627
bit rate: 705600 bits per second
packet size upper bound: 4
maximum packet size: 4
audio data file offset: 54
optimized
source bit depth: I16
----
```

Comment: This may have worked for me to force indexing on- i'll report back in a while.  I'd forgotten that I shut it off.

Comment: No, forcing indexing doesn't seem to fix the issue.  Also, I'm looking for the audio duration and bit rate to be displayed in the finder UI, not the terminal.  FWIW, the metadata is _certainly_ there, and it does display via afinfo in the terminal.